# Collect all meta.x.stackexchange.com votes to meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, meta

I did not find a previous proposal (but it may have been already discussed):

- The upvotes gained on the various meta subsites of the Stack Exchange network do not count for the *local* reputation and that's quite natural. This is clearly [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design).
- The meta.stackoverflow.com is the only SE site where you build reputation by discussing the characteristics, features and bugs of stackexchange network sites.

So, I would find it good that all reputation collected on the various meta sites be added to the meta.stackoverflow.com reputation. You would then have one "meta" reputation across all sites, but local meta discussions would stay local as needed.

Comment: meta.stackexchange.com redirects you to meta.stackoverflow.com, which is this site. I don't know any site matching meta.x.stackoverflow.com. Which sites are those?

Comment: @kiamlaluno...OP's taking about these kind of sites: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kiamlaluno : thanks for the edit, my title was misleading. Meta.stackexchange.com used to be a separate site.

Answer (score 6):

I think you'd find that there would be questions asked on meta.X.stackexchange.com sites which should be *moved* to meta.stackoverflow.com for discussion here...and any reputation associated would belong and be awarded here.

Combining the rep across all the metas just isn't useful or correct. There will be meta-type discussions at all the meta sites that are irrelevant to meta.stackoverflow.com and thus gaining reputation here for those questions/answers is misleading.

Comment: my reasoning is close to yours. It is that meta.stackoverflow.com has become a kind of higher court. Not only a meta of S.O. but a meta of all metas. So naturally some local meta questions should be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com but it would not be absurd that reputation gained in working on the meta aspects of other S.E. sites be taken into account there.